# Kotlin: CancellationException unwrapping in coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions, cancellation

I have found next statement in the documentation:

> Cancellation exceptions are transparent and are unwrapped by default:

```
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception -> println("CoroutineExceptionHandler got $exception")
}
val job = GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
    val inner = launch { // all this stack of coroutines will get cancelled 
        launch {
            launch {
                throw IOException() // the original exception
            } 
        }
    }
    try {
        inner.join()
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        println("Rethrowing CancellationException with original cause")
        throw e // cancellation exception is rethrown, yet the original IOException gets to the handler
    } 
}
job.join()
```

**What do this documentation means in terms of this code?**

**UPDATE 27-03-2021**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        println("CoroutineExceptionHandler got $exception")
    }
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
        launch {
            throw IOException() // the original exception
        }
        launch {
            throw CancellationException("Test", ArithmeticException("Arithmetic"))
        }
    }
    job.join()
}
```

Why in this case result is:

```
CoroutineExceptionHandler got java.io.IOException
```

Without Arithmetic exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inner.join()` throws a `CancellationException` with cause set to the exception that was thrown inside the job. But when a `CancellationException` is thown at top level, the `CoroutineExceptionHandler` will only see an `IOException` (the cause of the `CancellationException`).

Comment: What is "transparent and are unwrapped by default"?

Comment: I think 'transparent' means it propagates through all the jobs and gets turned into CancellationException, and 'unwrapped' means that the CoroutineExceptionHandler sees not the CancellationException but the IOException

Comment: But if in the cancel method Throwable will be specified, would it be used as a cause for this Job too?

Comment: Yes. They mean that IFF a CancellationException is thrown at top level, it ends up at the CoroutineExceptionHandler unwrapped.

Comment: I have added an update to the question, Arithmetic exception is not added as suppressed, why?

Comment: This issue is killing me could you direct me please?